# Using C# online, how do I read Text files from my computer?

Tags: c#, text-files, readline

Using http://rextester.com compiler, I want to read a text file from my computer. I don't have C# downloaded on this computer so I'm using the online version.

Here is my code. I want to convert all my lines into a string array.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace Rextester
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<String> lines = File.ReadLines("C:\\Users\\<<NAME>>\\Desktop\\new 2.txt");
        }
    }
}
```

`<<NAME>>` is replaced by my computer's username (censored it for privacy reasons).

Unfortunately the file cannot be found and it gave me this error. `The name 'File' does not exist in the current context`.

How do I get the online C# compiler to read TXT files from my computer?

Comment: I don't know if that is even possible. Try it with with a FileDialog.

Comment: The [File](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file(v=vs.110).aspx) class is in the System.IO namespace. You would need to either fully qualify your usage of the file class `System.IO.File.ReadLines` or add a using statement `using System.IO;` to the top of your class. Is this code actually running on the same machine where the file is located? I looked at their site and didn't see a way to download the resulting program to your computer to run.

Comment: You may not have installed Visual Studio, but if you are running Windows there is a free compiler, look in your hard drive for `csc.exe`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For starters, you need a reference to `System.IO` (I think) to use File.

Secondly, you do not, *not*, and I repeat, *NOT* want some website to read files from your computer like that.
Even if somehow your online program knew that `C:\`means your hard drive, and not mine, or one of millions of other disks that are called `C:\` (and it doesn't, because `C:\` would refer to th elocal machine the program runs on, so it would Always be the C drive of the server your program runs on!), if your program *could* read from *your* C-drive, that would mean *I* can also read from your hard drive. Would you want that?

By the way, to write C# on your own machine (and run it) you don't need to "install C#". There are plenty of free editors and compilers around. Even Microsoft Visual Studio comes in a free-to-use version, the Community Edition. If you want to pick up programming, give it (or any of the alternatives) a try :)

Comment: `c:\ ` would only ever refer to the C drive on the computer the program runs on.  It would never refer to anything else.  That's ridiculous.

Comment: Yeah you're right. It's not secure that way. Just thought this was a feature available online.

Comment: And windows (all recent windows) ship with some .net tools, including a compiler. I would encourage using a IDE like Visual Studio Community Edition tho.

Answer (score 2):

Your browser will not give a website full access to your computer's file system. That's a huge security feature that needs to be in place.

If rextester allows uploading single files with JavaScript it may create a "fake" filesystem that c# could access.

If not, then you would need to write c# code that would go to the internet, find your computer, login, and read your filesystem that way. FTP might be a good choice, as allowing direct filesystem access to the internet is risky.

Answer (score 1):

You can't. Rextester has no way of accessing your file system. In general, browsers don't, other than estabilishing upload/download through an OS prompt. Think of the consequences if a website could read an arbitrary file on your computer.